# Retain comments inside R expression

Tags: r, rlang

```
my_expr <- expr({
  # this is a comment
  this_is_code
})
my_expr
```

returns:

```
{
  this_is_code
}
```

But i'd like it to return:

```
{
  # this is a comment
  this_is_code
}
```

Is retaining the comment possible using rlang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is already retained, it just doesn't get printed to the console. Check out `attr(my_expr, "wholeSrcref")`.